# Why I have different result conversion text to double

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have code here which will convert **`String`** value to **`Double`** with 2 decimal places. 
 When the **`myStrValue`** is **`820`** the final result is **`8.2`** - **`which is wrong result`** it should be **`8.20`**

> I have code here:

```
string myStrValue = "820";

double myDblValue = Convert.ToDouble(myStrValue) * 0.01; 
double finalValue = Math.Round(myDblValue, 2);
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Numbers `8.2` and `8.20` are exactly the same. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Trailing decimal zeros are automatically ignored unless you ask it to format it to the right number of decimal places

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(finalValue.ToString("0.00"));` If it's just for displaying your number and see your `8.2` is `8.20`.

Comment: so there are no chance to make it 8.20? in  double datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> final result is 8.2 - which is wrong result it should be 8.20

please don't mix up the number at hand and it's represenation as string when you display it. Mathematically 8.2 and 8.20 are the same numbers and are treated the same way.

On the other hand the string representation is controled by you when you decide to display it.

You can determine the format of display in different ways:

```
finalValue.ToString("0.00");
string rep = $"{finalValue:0.00}";
// and many more, google will find it
```

> so there are no chance to make it 8.20? in double datatype?

Actually NO, because in datatype `double` it is saved entirely different, with an exponent and mantissa. If you are interested have a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b34tf65.aspx)

But the representation of it will have no effect if you want to use the number.
Because `finalValue + 0.001` will result in `8.201`.